# Java Subclasses last instance overwriting values

Tags: java

I'm a web developer dabbling in Java (again) and I'm having trouble with something.

Basically, I have a superclass Employee with two subclasses that extend it called Management and Programmer. The Employee class contains an array `employees` that is basically an array of Employee objects.

Here's the important snippets of two of the classes (Employee and Management) and the final main method. I'll explain the output at the bottom.

```
public class **Employee** {

   private static String firstName;
   protected static int MAXEMPLOYEES = 5;
   protected Employee[] employees = new Employee[MAXEMPLOYEES];
   protected int totEmployees = 0;

   public Employee(String first) {
       setFirstName(first);
   }

   public void setFirstName(String str){
       firstName = str;
   }

   public String getFirstName(){
       return firstName;
   }

    public boolean addEmployee(String fname) {
       boolean added = false;
       if (totEmployees < MAXEMPLOYEES) {
           Employee empl = new Employee(fname);
           employees[totEmployees] = empl;
           added = true;
           totEmployees++;
       }
       return added;
   }

}

public class **Management** extends **Employee** {
    private String title = "Project Manager";

    public Management(String fname, String t){
        super(fname);
        title = t;
    }

    public boolean addManagement(String fname, String t){
        boolean added = false;

        if (totEmployees < MAXEMPLOYEES) {
            employees[totEmployees] = new Management(fname, t);
            added = true;
            totEmployees++;
        }
        return added;
    }
}

-------------------------------------
package employee;

public class EmployeeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee[] empl = new Employee[3];
        empl[0] = new Employee("Kyle");
        empl[1] = new Management("Sheree", "Director");

        System.out.println(empl[0].getFirstName());
    }
}
```

Now, I expect the system to print out "Kyle", but it prints out "Sheree". Any ideas???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private static String firstName;
```

You made `firstName` static, which means all instances share the same name.  You'll need to remove the static modifier in order for different Employees to have different names.  You'll also need to change the private access modifier to protected in order for the field to be inherited by subclasses.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. I feel a tad idiotic but that's perfect! Thanks so much (I will accept as answer in 7 minutes, apparently :-))

Comment: @KyleO'Brien You're welcome. It's easy to miss some of the details if you haven't done OOP before (or sometimes even if you have, in a different language).

Comment: Meh, coding in PHP isn't this anal :P

Answer (score 2):

```
private String firstName;
```

remove `static`;

Kyle was overridden by Sheree, that is why you are getting that output